# Perspective projection of a 3D object, without use of WPF or DirectX or XNA or OpenGL or game engine

Tags: .net, graphics, 3d

I'm looking for some code example (preferably C#) or a simple .Net function library, cheap or free, that I can use to transform a 3D thing into a 2D perspective projection of it, given specified camera location, etc.

I've searched and searched, but everything I find seems to make use of a major graphics framework or is very device-oriented, or both. I want something that is pure software and device-independent and will work with .Net 2.

But I do want real perspective projection with a camera view, not just some 2D image transformation that skews the image so it looks somewhat perspectivey.

Edit:

Thanks to those who have answered. Like I say, I've already spent a lot of time searching, so I'm not so surprised that the answer (so far) is that I'm looking for something that doesn't exist.

In response to questions as to why I'm allergic to getting involved with some major package, the reason is simply the "keep it simple" rule. To me, what I'm trying to do is one little bit of graphics manipulation, and I can't get my head around the idea of having to become familiar with a huge multi-purpose package that implements 10,000+ functions in order that I can do my one little function.

Edit 2 - mostly for Miky:

The following is a rambling bit of pseudo programmer philosophy to try again to justify my desire to avoid getting involved with any large and complicated package when all I want is one very specific function. Don't waste your time reading this unless you really have nothing better to do ...

Miky points out, correctly, that the .Net Framework has a gazillion functions, and yet I chose to learn how to use it even though I'll never use even 1% of 1% of those functions. Yes, but I am using several hundred of them, and that makes it all worthwhile. (Memory management alone is a function to die for.)

I am also using the Developer Express package for WinForms, and it also contains thousands and thousands of functions that I'll never use. But I do use the ribbon menu and the docking panels and the grid and the tree view and dozens of other functions, maybe a hundred or more, and that makes it all worthwhile.

I am also using the MindFusion charting for WinForms product, and it contains hundreds of functions that I'll never use, but I do use the functions that support the creation of organization charts and floorplans and moving nodes around and linking them together and reformatting the chart and zooming in and out and undo ... maybe I'm using several dozen functions and that makes it all worthwhile.

So here I am with a program containing 170,000 lines of code and highly dependent on .Net Framework and Developer Express and somewhat dependent on MindFusion, and now I want to do one tiny bit of 3D perspective rendering. In fact, it's not even real 3D - **what I want to do is display a 2D image (a floorplan) as seen from an oblique angle. I want to stack floorplans one above another to represent a transparent multi-story building, perhaps with exaggerated inter-floorplan spacing, and to allow the user to specify if he/she wants to look at the pseudo-building from one corner or face-on or another corner, and the elevation of the camera.**

That's it. What I think I need is one or two C# methods that will let me **render these 2D floorplans floating in space as if they are 3D because they are tilted relative to the camera, and to move the camera around**. Nothing more.

And rightly or wrongly, I am convinced that if I start getting involved with having to learn a major 3D universe-creating package or a device/performance oriented graphics system, then I will end up using more time than this feature is worth. And I definitely don't want to bloat the runtime footprint of my program with megabytes of modules that will never be used.

But I do appreciate all the suggestions and attention this question has received.

Comment: So you what you are essentially looking for is a 3D Drawing library that is not DirectX, XNA, or OpenGL, or any Game Engine. Why not any of those listed above? By the way, I doubt that one exists for .NET. If you can find one it's probably going to be written for un-managed code (think C/C++).

Comment: The keywords you want are "C# software renderer".  Since you're looking for software-only, "C# ray tracer" might also fit your needs.

Comment: Also, the unfortunate fact is that any kind of rendering is going to bring a fair amount of complexity with it.  Real perspective projection is pretty simple by itself.  However, loading/generating/representing 3D objects and their visual appearance is also necessary, and much more complex than the projection part...

Comment: @RenniePet - I've just edited your question a tiny bit. I fixed my name, and made a couple paragraphs bold. That's really what your question should be asking. The more precise you get the better the community will be able to help out! P.S. Thanks for your confidence in my salesmanship abilities :)

Comment: And one last note. If you don't get the answer you are looking for on this question, please post another and focus on the specific details you need help with! This one might be too off-putting with all the lengthy dissertations..

Comment: Are these floorplans drawn with lines or bitmaps? If they are only lines, all you need is a matrix math library and GDI. If you need perspective correct bitmap rendering, you need more. If you don't want d3d or opengl, reconsider WPF 3D. All you need is .net 3.5, and almost no one has .net 2 anymore.. see http://statowl.com/microsoft_dotnet.php

Comment: And HTML5 can do perspective texture mapping too: http://panoramas.dk/mars/greeley-haven.html

Comment: @jdv-JandeVann: They are bitmaps, a kind of snapshot of the vector-based chart produced by the MindFusion program. As for WPF, my program is WinForms-based - is it possible (or a good idea) to try to mix WinForms and WPF? Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, projecting a 3D shape onto a 2D screen just means using geometry to say, if my screen was a window into a 3D world, where on the screen would each point in that object appear?

[image]

You can work out the answer with similar triangles, if you know the distance you want the user's eye to seem to be away from the screen:

[image]

The math would just be:

[image: sx = tx * DISTANCE / ty]

Comment: Thanks. Cute pictures. I am aware of the math for the simple theoretical case that you show. I've written a little program based on this Code Project article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2158/A-short-discussion-on-mapping-3D-objects-to-a-2D-d

Comment: But maybe I'm too dumb or something, but what I think I need is an actual program that just works, a program where you plug in the 3D object and the camera position and camera angle, and a 2D image comes out the other end. Specifically, based on the mentioned article my program is projecting a box-like object and the result is a square, which is just fine. But when I move my camera to one side I would expect the front face of the box to become non-square - the nearest edge should be longer than the edge farther away. But the face of the box remains square. So I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: If you are shifting the camera to one side, keeping it pointed in one direction, you would indeed expect the front of the box to remain square. Only if the box is rotated would that face be non-square.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know such a library. The usual approach is to use homogenous coordinates. This works but is quite abstract.

To tackle the problem, I'd first write the program using the math library that comes with SlimDx or Xna.

Once that works, port the functions you need to your own C# code. Whatever library you begin with, the transforms and perspective matrix functions are all the same, and their definitions can be found on the internet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question. I was hoping for something simple, but ... I may try what you suggest. But although SlimDX is open source, I'm guessing the perspective rendering isn't in the source because that is done by DirectX, right?

Answer (score 1):

While I can conceive of some reasons why you don't want a dependency on Microsoft specific frameworks, or event OpenGL I'm really struggling to understand what you have against 3D libraries for games.

The problem is that most 3D libraries have game developers in mind because they form the majority of the user-base.

So, if you're inclined to leniency on that final restriction your possibilities brighten slightly. However one problem still remains.

Nobody really bothers much with 3D libraries for .NET.. That's because for .NET there is already DirectX, XNA, OpenGL.. and again, since most 3D library users are after performance first, the focus is on C or C++.

So, that leaves you with options in the un-managed territory including libraries such as:

- [PolyCode](http://polycode.org/)
- [iirLicht](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/features/)

Regarding your edit:

I think that in this case you'd be best served by fighting your inhibition and getting up to speed on the basics of one of those intimidating packages. Think about it this way:

The .NET framework has 10,000+ methods and if you wanted to create a simple application that displayed a windows with a button that updates the text printed on a label it would still be easier to learn the little bit necessary (a few basic prinicples and subset of functions) to accomplish that than to try to look for a light-weight library designed to display windows with buttons and text boxes.

The analogy above holds for all major 3D libraries. The reason they feel indimidating is presumably partly because it's all new territory and also because 3D graphics is not a super-simple concept to grasp. And so anybody implementing a 3D library will want to expose as much functionality as possible to make the developers life easier (not harder).

The good news is that picking up the basics of say OpenGL or DirectX is really not that hard. Learning/using DirectX *may* be easier with .NET. Learning OpenGL may suit you better long-term as it is more portable. And both have the advantage of having many many resources available to get people started.

So, bite the bullet! Don't reinvent the wheel and don't be afraid to take on a large dependency (when you know it's the right one)! And get on with writing your first basic 3D-enabled application. **You'll feel better**!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please see edit to my question. I've taken a quick look at the PolyCode features page, and I feel totally intimidated. Own IDE, one-click publishing, hardware-accelerated graphics, font rendering, animation, mesh, particles, sound, networking, physics ...  All I want is a little C# routine that will do a perspective rendering. But thanks again for your help

Comment: You should be a salesman! (Just for you, Niky, I've edited my question again. And I really do appreciate your help.)

Comment: Very sorry about getting your name wrong, I hate making mistakes like that.